# NodeJS - reading file from S3 to /tmp folder in Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, copy, fs

I have a need to move `*.dbf` file for further processing from S3 bucket to `/tmp` folder in Lambda. So far file is moving but the content of file becomes corrupted, what am I doing wrong?

```
exports.getS3Object = ( bucket, key ) => {

  return S3Client.getObject( {

    Bucket              : bucket,
    Key                 : key
  } )
  .promise( )
  .then( file => {

    console.log( 'File loading ', key );
    if ( ! fs.existsSync( '/tmp' ) ) {

      fs.mkdirSync( '/tmp' );
    }
    fs.writeFileSync( '/tmp/' + key, file.Body.toString( 'utf8' ), ( error ) => {

      throw error;  
    } ); 
    return '/tmp/' + key;
  } )
  .catch( error => {

    // file not found
    return error;
  } );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `dbf` file is probably not encoded as a `utf8` string. Try `base64` or `binary` encoding when calling `file.Body.toString`.